# Git usename does not change

Tags: git

I reset the username using git config user.name both globally and locally.

But as below image, it is always set to username 'git'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the user.name variable in your repository config is only used for authorship of commits. The username that you see when attempting to push to gitlab is actually contained in the remote URI.

If you run `git remote -v` the output will show the URL with the username (e.g. `origin git@github.com:username/project.git`).

To change it, assuming the remote is origin, you can delete the remote and re-add it with the changed username.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin newuser@gitlab.com/path/to/project.git
```

Answer (score 0):

@Markus in above answer is right. There is another way however to view and update it manually if you don't remember the commands.

Go to you `.git` and open `config` file in your favorite editor i.e. vim. There you can see `URL` that will be used for push for your named `origin`.

Change that `URL` and you are good for push.

Also remember that you have same global `config` file, in your home directory, double check that place if local file gives you trouble.

Happy coding :)